# What method Mathematica uses to solve a quadratic system

Tags: equation-solving, algorithm

I'am writing a paper and I need to know what method Mathematica uses to solve a quadratic system by default.

This is my system:

```
ydl = 1;
yinfl = 1;
U2 = 1;
U1 = -0.2;

solve = NSolve[
          {L + δw/2 == yinfl, L + yd == ydl, (U2 - U1)/(-U1*L - U1*yd)*yd^2/2 == δw,
           δw > 0, L > 0, yd > 0, δw > yd}, 
          {L, δw, yd}, Reals];
```

Comment: There is a somewhat dated explanation [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228403380_Solving_finite_algebraic_systems_using_numeric_Grobner_bases_and_eigenvalues). An [update](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/amaletzk/ICMS2018-GB.html) will appear in a few months.

Comment: Is that the actual equation involved? If so, you can rationalize the parameter `U1`, replacing it by `-1/5`, and then use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`, so as to get an exact solution.

Comment: What method `Solve` uses by default? @murray

Comment: Could check [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ComplexPolynomialSystems.html).

Comment: The document doesn't explain how the method works